# Unable to ping CentOS virtualbox

Tags: networking, centos, virtualbox

I have created a virtual machine for CentOS in VirtualBox using an NAT connection (It won't work under Bridged). Now the problem is I can ping from CentOS to my IP on Ubuntu with no problem but I cannot ping from Ubuntu or from my work terminal to `CentOS`. I have disabled `ufw` on Ubuntu and still cannot get ping. I have disabled `iptables`,`ip6tables`, and `selinux` on CentOS and still cannot get a response. Is there something else that may be preventing me from pinging that I overlooked?

FYI I have been successfully able to ping www.google.com and surf the web so I know it is not a network problem from Ubuntu's end or even my work putty terminal but something is getting lost somewhere.

Comment: are they on the same network/router?

Comment: Yes I would be on the same network. I will be doing additional testing when I get out of work but I highly doubt my work's network is preventing me from accessing the ftp server, we don't have a strict policy

Comment: if tech comp it's likely. My company doesn't allow....

Comment: I certainly wont rule it out but usually we are pretty lenient when it comes to projects like this..

Comment: What type of networking did you tell virtualbox to use for the centos VM? Is ubuntu also a VM?

Comment: CentOS is NAT and Ubuntu is my OS on my laptop

Comment: Are you able to ping by IP address?

Comment: Yes, I can ping on both machines by IP addresses. I just cannot ping from Ubuntu or my work terminal to CentOS.

Comment: Add the entry of the virtual machine to the `/etc/hosts` file in the Ubuntu machine and try again. I believe the hostname cannot be resolved which is why ping is not working.

Comment: @OP can you ssh from host to guest? Can you telnet port 22? Have you forwarded it?

Comment: Virtualbox's NAT networking isn't going to allow incoming connections unless you set up port forwarding for specific ports. Try bridged. Suggest reading the networking chapter of the virtualbox manual to see the pros and cons of each networking choice.

Comment: I cant use bridged because it wont allow me to go online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flush the `iptables` rules just in case (`iptables -F`).

With the network in bridge mode (I assume that was what you were after ideally) run `wireshark` on the Ubuntu machine and watch for DHCP requests. If you see a request but no response then you're likely looking at network restrictions. Either way `wireshark` will help you get a better of idea what is happening.

Comment: Thanks this helped alot. I think that company restrictions are keeping me from making a connection.